# Is it possible to download an asset from an entries tab

Tags: assets, control-panel, plugins

I was wondering if there was a plugin that would give my client the ability to download an asset – in this case a submitted resume – when viewing an entry in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there isn't currently a plugin which makes that possible ([complete list is here](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins)), but I'd imagine it's possible to build one.

The trick would be to set it up as a [Field Type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types). Then your field type would have to dynamically figure out what file is supposed to be downloaded, and provide a button for your user to download it.

Comment: I had looked through the plugin list mentioned. I was hoping there was something in the works somewhere. Creating a plugin isn't in the cards for e at the moment. Thanks for the help though.